# Performance counter MSSQLInstance\SQL Errors\Errors/sec\User Errors whats in it?

Tags: sql-server, windows, server, performancecounter

Im wondering what kind of errors would show up in:

```
SQL Errors\Errors/sec\User errors
```

[Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188237.aspx) just says:

```
Information about user errors.
```

I need more info, what events cause this counter to increment?

Comment: [Here is what seems to be the exact same question in dba.StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62603/performance-counter-mssqlinstance-sql-errors-errors-sec-info-errors-whats-in-it), but this is with answers...

Comment: I saw that which is for info errors, this is for user errors